# IK error : Planning scene not set

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

when trying to run the IK solver I got this error:

> [ERROR] [1340129176.933085357]: Inverse kinematics failed

with rxconsole I got this error:

> Planning scene not set

when I looked at the log I got this error:

> [0m] [ INFO] [1340111949.225789190]Did you set the log to debug? You can't know much with just one error: everything seems to be connected correctly as you're able to start / interrogate the service. But the IK is failing somehow. : Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server to come up.

Any ideas please,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36832/ik-error-:-planning-scene-not-set/) by [robot_arm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2613/robot_arm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are running constraint aware IK. It's always good to provide as much information as possible in question (see also [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support)).

As the error says, you didn't set a planning scene. Just call the service `/environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff`. You can keep the SetPlanningSceneDiff service request empty. From the command line, you can set the planning scene by executing:

```
rosservice call /environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff '{}'
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2